# Getting an excel macro to run each time a line is changed

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Excel macro and right now it runs every time there is any change in the worksheet. I would like it to only run on lines that have changed since the worksheet is large enough to lag for a second or two every time it runs.

Is this possible? Also is it possible to run on any line in any worksheet in the workbook if that line is changed?

Module1:

```
Function ValidNumber(NUM1 As Integer, NUM2 As Integer) As Boolean
    If (IsNumeric(Cells(NUM1, NUM2).Value) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(NUM1, NUM2).Value)) Then
        ValidNumber = True
    Else
        ValidNumber = False
    End If
End Function

Sub Calculate1(NUM As Integer)
    Dim EntryPrice As Double
    Dim ExitPrice As Double
    Dim Invested As Double
    Dim PL As Double
    Dim Margin As Double
    Dim InvestPercentage As Double
    
    If (Cells(NUM, 6).Value = "L" And ValidNumber(NUM, 7) And ValidNumber(NUM, 8) And ValidNumber(NUM, 10)) Then
        EntryPrice = Cells(NUM, 7)
        ExitPrice = Cells(NUM, 8)
        Invested = Cells(NUM, 10)
        
        InvestPercentage = (Invested / EntryPrice) * 100
        PL = ((ExitPrice / 100) * InvestPercentage) - Invested
        Margin = PL / Invested
        
        If (Cells(NUM, 8) < Cells(NUM, 7)) Then
            Cells(NUM, 8).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Cells(NUM, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        ElseIf (Cells(NUM, 8) > Cells(NUM, 7) And Cells(NUM, 8) < Cells(NUM, 9)) Then
            Cells(NUM, 8).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Cells(NUM, 8).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 140, 0)
        Else
            Cells(NUM, 8).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Cells(NUM, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
        End If
        
        If (PL > 0) Then
            Cells(NUM, 11).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Cells(NUM, 11).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
            Cells(NUM, 12).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Cells(NUM, 12).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
        Else
            Cells(NUM, 11).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Cells(NUM, 11).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Cells(NUM, 12).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Cells(NUM, 12).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If

        Cells(NUM, 11).Value = PL
        Cells(NUM, 12).Value = Margin
    ElseIf (Cells(NUM, 6).Value = "S" And ValidNumber(NUM, 7) And ValidNumber(NUM, 8) And ValidNumber(NUM, 10)) Then
        EntryPrice = Cells(NUM, 7)
        ExitPrice = Cells(NUM, 8)
        Invested = Cells(NUM, 10)
        
        InvestPercentage = (Invested / EntryPrice) * 100
        PL = ((ExitPrice / 100) * InvestPercentage) - Invested
        Margin = PL / Invested
        
        If (Cells(NUM, 8) > Cells(NUM, 7)) Then
            Cells(NUM, 8).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Cells(NUM, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        ElseIf (Cells(NUM, 8) < Cells(NUM, 7) And Cells(NUM, 8) > Cells(NUM, 9)) Then
            Cells(NUM, 8).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Cells(NUM, 8).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 140, 0)
        Else
            Cells(NUM, 8).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Cells(NUM, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
        End If
        
        If (PL < 0) Then
            Cells(NUM, 11).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Cells(NUM, 11).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
            Cells(NUM, 12).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Cells(NUM, 12).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
            PL = Abs(PL)
            Margin = Abs(Margin)
        Else
            Cells(NUM, 11).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Cells(NUM, 11).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Cells(NUM, 12).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Cells(NUM, 12).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            PL = -Abs(PL)
            Margin = -Abs(Margin)
        End If
        
        Cells(NUM, 11).Value = PL
        Cells(NUM, 12).Value = Margin
    Else
        Cells(NUM, 8).Interior.Color = xlNone
        Cells(NUM, 11).Interior.Color = xlNone
        Cells(NUM, 12).Interior.Color = xlNone
        Cells(NUM, 8).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Cells(NUM, 11).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Cells(NUM, 12).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Cells(NUM, 11).Clear
        Cells(NUM, 12).Clear
    End If
    
    
    Range("B:B").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
    Range("K:K").NumberFormat = "$#0.00"
    Range("L:L").NumberFormat = "#0.00000%"
End Sub
    
Sub CalculatePL()
    For i = 3 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        Calculate1 (i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Sheet1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For i = 3 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        Calculate1 (i)
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For i = 3 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        Calculate1 (i)
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `Sub Worksheet_Activate()` and revise `Sub Worksheet_Change` as below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Calculate1 (Target.Row)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: So I added this to each worksheet. So Sheet1, Sheet2 etc all have this stub in them. Calculate1 is in a module. I have input these exactly as you have in your answer and they are not working.

There is no errors or any output at all making me think somewhere along the way I have set these up wrong. Do you have any ideas on how I could debug this?

Comment: Please run `Application.EnableEvents = True` in VBE immediate window first to make sure the event can be triggered. Your `Worksheet_Change` call `Calculate1` to validate all data rows ( from 3 to UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1). The new code only validate the changed row. e.g. if users change cell `B5`, then it call `Calculate1(5)`. I am not clear about the logic in `Calculate1`.